# Retrieve mysql data as a listView in an android fragment

Tags: android, mysql, listview, fragment

I'm an android beginner, and I'm trying to find a way to retrieve data from a mysql database into a ListView, but in a Fragment instead of in an Activity. Is that even possible? Can someone give me some advises??

Comment: If you are an android beginner i recommend the Udacity android beginner course. https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853 it's free and awsome, don't expect it to be easy though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a looooong search, finally I've found a solution

http://codeoncloud.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html

I used this code in my fragment, and it worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you can create a ListView in the frgamentLayout and use that listview in the fragment by using findViewById.

Then you can create a function which returns all the data from the mysql as a List and you can set that list data to the LsiyView by using an adapter.

I have already tried it once and it worked fine.

Comment: good to know that it's possible! Can you please show me how can I do it?